# Handling/Avoiding Timeout Exceptions / cancellation tokens using Async Tasks in Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

## Summary

How do I either avoid a `TimeoutException` or continue rendering the page after a `TimeoutException` when using async Pages in ASP.NET WebForms?

What point does the `PageAsyncTask` cancellation token serve if it can't be used to avoid the `Timeout Exception`?

## Details

I am calling an async endpoint to get results to display in a WebForms page.  Mostly this works fine, however, when the endpoint takes too long to return a result, the whole page yellow screens with

```
[TimeoutException: An asynchronous operation exceeded the page timeout.
```

I don't want to simply increase the `Page.AsyncTimeout` arbitrarily.  Instead, I want to to handle the timeout and process the rest of the page displaying my own message for the section of the page relying on the timed out async task.

For the constructor

```cs
public PageAsyncTask (Func<System.Threading.CancellationToken,System.Threading.Tasks.Task> handler);
```

the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.pageasynctask.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-web-ui-pageasynctask-ctor(system-func((system-threading-cancellationtoken-system-threading-tasks-task)))) states:

> ASP.NET will signal the CancellationToken object that is passed to a TaskEventHandler delegate for cancellation based on the AsyncTimeout attribute set in the @ Page directive of the Web page. When the AsyncTimeout value has been reached, the CancellationToken object will be signaled. The CancellationToken parameter must be passed to any asynchronous APIs that are called by your implementation of the TaskEventHandler class.

However, even when I do that, I still get the page level `TimeoutException`.

A different [overload of the constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.pageasynctask.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-web-ui-pageasynctask-ctor(system-web-begineventhandler-system-web-endeventhandler-system-web-endeventhandler-system-object)) provides a timeout handler

```cs
public PageAsyncTask (System.Web.BeginEventHandler beginHandler, System.Web.EndEventHandler endHandler, System.Web.EndEventHandler timeoutHandler, object state);
```

However there appears to be no means to use a `Task` with a `timeoutHandler`. This seems to imply that handling the cancellationToken should be sufficient, but apparently it is not.

Furthermore, the `TimeoutException` appears to be thrown at a point where it is impossible to actually catch it in a useful (for my purposes) way - the `Page.Error` event seems to be too late to recover rendering of the page.

Which seems to beg the additional question of what is the point of using `public PageAsyncTask (Func<System.Threading.CancellationToken,System.Threading.Tasks.Task> handler);` instead of `public PageAsyncTask (Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> handler);`?

## Sample Code

*Default.aspx*

```
<%@ Page Async="true" AsyncTimeout="5" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Foo.Default" %>
<%-- ... --%>
<form runat="server">
  <asp:Button ID="btnGetInfo" runat="server" Text="Get Info" onclick="btnGetInfo_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtInfo" runat="server" />
  <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" />
<%-- ... --%>
</form>
```

*Default.aspx.cs*

```cs
namespace Foo
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private readonly DummyService _dummyService = new DummyService();

        protected void btnGetInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtInfo.Text = "";
            lblError.Text = "";

            async Task btnGetInfoClickAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                //also tried:
                //cancellationToken.Register(() => lblError.Text = "Timeout, data not retrieved", useSynchronizationContext: true);  

                try
                {
                    string info = await _dummyService.GetInfoAsync(cancellationToken);

                    txtInfo.Text = info;
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException)
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Timeout, data not retrieved";
                }
            }

            RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(btnGetInfoClickAsync));
        }
    }
}
```

*DummyService.cs*

```cs
namespace Foo
{
    public class DummyService
    {
        public async Task<string> GetInfoAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await Task.Delay(6000, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return Path.GetRandomFileName();
        }
    }
}
```

*Web.config*

```xml
<configuration>
  <!-- ... -->
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8">
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8">
    <!-- ... -->
  </system.web>
  <!-- ... -->
</configuration>
```

Comment: `AsyncTimeout="5"` <-- Why is this so short?

Comment: You can't avoid trouble once a `TimeoutException` or `OperationCanceledException` has been thrown: the thrower (or methods in the throw/catch chain) will have already reverted/rolled-back their changes (or at least, they're meant to...).

Comment: What you should be doing here is running the `Task` in the background using `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` (and storing a key or some way to retrieve the task from elsewhere), and returning a redirection response to the user to a page with that key in the querystring and a"Please wait" message and a JS script that reloads the page (with the key in the querystring being used to determine the background task status).

Comment: @Dai timeout is short for the sake of demonstrating the general issue in a small reproducible sample.

Comment: @Dai `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` etc seems a bit of a mismatch for this use-case, and at any rate is a separate approach from what is documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45

Comment: To be fair to myself, you didn't describe the kinds of operations your page will be carrying out (i.e. very-long-running operations that take longer than ~1 second should use `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`) - but honestly I don't know why you want to use `AsyncTimeout=""` at all here... In my own WebForms projects (that have since migrated over to AspNetCore, phew!) I set `AsyncTimeout=""` to a high value as its purpose is meant to be a watchdog for never-ending page-loads (so something like 60-90 seconds): if WebForms throws its `TimeoutException` then _something really bad has happened_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to avoid the `TimeoutException` and allow continuing to process the page is to:

- Use the `PageAsyncTask (Func<Task> handler)` constructor instead of the `PageAsyncTask (Func<CancellationToken, Task> handler)` constructor
- Provide your own cancellation token that expires before `Page.AsyncTimeout`.

This assumes that the async api your are calling accepts and properly responds to a `CancellationToken`.

e.g.
*Default.aspx.cs*

```cs
namespace Foo
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private readonly DummyService _dummyService = new DummyService();

        private CancellationToken _cancellationToken;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource((int)Page.AsyncTimeout.TotalMilliseconds - 1000).Token;
        }

        protected void btnGetInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtInfo.Text = "";
            lblError.Text = "";

            async Task btnGetInfoClickAsync()
            {
                try
                {
                    string info = await _dummyService.GetInfoAsync(_cancellationToken);

                    txtInfo.Text = info;
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException)
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Timeout, data not retrieved";
                }
            }

            RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(btnGetInfoClickAsync));
        }
    }
}
```

(I still don't understand the utility of the `PageAsyncTask (Func<CancellationToken, Task> handler);` constructor)